# How to find $E(X)$ and $E(X^2)$ for a normal distribution from known values of $\mu$ and $\sigma$?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expected-value

I am self-studying an introductory course on probability and am attempting some questions to test my understanding. As I have only just started I am confused on where to begin with a problem like this:

> Given that $X$ is a Normally distributed random variable with mean $\mu=4$ and standard deviation $\sigma=2$. How do I calculate $E(X)$ and $E(X^2)$?

I am looking for a hint or a prompt. I have no idea where to start. This may be due to an issue with my understanding of the notation and how mean, variance, and standard deviation connect to $E(X)$ and $E(X^2)$ which feel like isolated quantities to me. It is also unclear to me how the fact that $X$ is Normally distributed relates to this problem as that also seems unconnected to what we are told.

I know that $E(X) := \int _{- \infty}^{\infty}x f(x) dx$ and $E(X^2) =  \int _{- \infty}^{\infty}x^2 f(x) dx$, however, these definitions that I have seen do some seem to depend at all on the constants $\mu$ and $\sigma$ which is leading to my confusion.

Comment: Since you ask for a hint, do you know how the variance of a random variable is defined?

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): edit your post to include at least the definitions of the notions involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: For any random variable with finite expectation the following holds:

$$Var(X) = \sigma ^2 = E(X^2)-E(X)^2$$

Note that $E(X)= \mu$, so you can now just substitute this in and rearrange.

There is nothing special about the Normal distribution being used here. This same argument works for the Binomial distribution, Poisson distribution, etc.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: This is kind of a circular argument, as to compute the variance, one generally needs to first compute the second moment

Comment: The question says that the mean and standard deviation are known. So there is no problem with this answer. Although I agree that other methods could solve more general problems (either by computing the relevant integral/sum or differentiating the moment generating function) @AndrewZhang

Comment: This question seems to go against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards).  Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.